# how to check the pipe symbol in java

Tags: java, regex, split

If I want to check the pipe symbol in the regular expression as shown below:

Earlier I used the below code for csv data:

```
fields = rowline.replaceAll("^\"", "").split(
                    "\"?(,|$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");
```

Now I want to change the above code, to check for pipe (`|`) seperated data.

Comment: `|` is a special chracter in regex. You will have to escape it using 2 backslashes in java

Comment: Use: `split( "\"?(\\||$)(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$) *\"?");`

Comment: can u plz explain that regular expression , Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`|` has a special meaning of `OR`, and a `'\|'` means a literal `'|'` so the string `"\\|"` means the regular expression `'\|'` which means match exactly the character `'|'`.

```
String[] list_str = line.split("\\|");
```

Or the helper `Pattern.quote()` which has been created for exactly this purpose:

```
string.split(Pattern.quote("|"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much ankur for your great response. can you plz help me to understand the regular expression .